# Mini-Profiler crashes on dbo.__MigrationHistory with EF-DB First

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm having some performance issues with my MVC3-Application. That's why I decided to implement mini-profiler.

[image]

I'm using MVC3 with EF (and Razor Views). Because I'm using the DB-first approach, there is no dbo.__MigrationHistory. So how do I tell Mini-Profiler to stop looking for it?

This is what I did:

Global.asax.cs:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ...
            MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
        }

        void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...
            MiniProfiler.Start();
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            MiniProfiler.Stop();
        }
```

I tried the [answer in this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539946/using-mini-profilier-with-ef-4-3-mvc-4-without-creating-the-database), but I'm unable to use 'Database' in my DBContext (DAL).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<CMDBContext>(null);
```

It looks like you have an existing property called Database like

```
    public new string  Database { get; set; }
```

in yourCMDBContext. Then when you refer to Database, you refer to that property. Since it is a property of the object, you cannot access it from static method/constructor.

Comment: So obvious now... Thanks!